# CRegExp error in Ipython

Tags: python, ipython

I love ipython, I am learning python now as a replacement of R for data analysis. However at promt I get the following message:

```
$ ipython --qtconsole
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/Current/bin/ipython", line 5, in <module>
    from IPython.frontend.terminal.ipapp import launch_new_instance
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
    from .frontend.terminal.embed import embed
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/frontend/terminal/embed.py", line 39, in <module>
    from IPython.frontend.terminal.interactiveshell import TerminalInteractiveShell
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/frontend/terminal/interactiveshell.py", line 33, in <module>
    from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell, InteractiveShellABC
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 44, in <module>
    from IPython.core import prefilter
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/prefilter.py", line 48, in <module>
    from IPython.utils.traitlets import (
ImportError: cannot import name CRegExp
```

Ipython worked just fine a week ago and now I get this error. Can anybody suggest what might be causing this?

Comment: Looks like either `utils.traitlets` got updated and `CRegExp` got deprecated (which would be weird), or some other black magic, like refactoring of `CRegExp` to another module, but the error literally means that module `utils.traitlets` has no `CRegExp` in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @favoretti mentioned, this is an import issue in `utils.traitlets`.

I would recommend upgrading to EPD 7.3 and see if that fixes the issue. I feel bad suggesting a "brush it under the carpet" solution but if you're just starting out with python delving into the bowels of IPython might be a bit of a headache.